# Activiti Forms, initial value for form property

Tags: java, jbpm, activiti

I'm using activiti 5.9 and I want to be able to set initial value for an specific form property.

this initial value should be used when variable with given id does not exist in process, and might be overwritten when user task gets completed by user and new value will stored in process variable.

I thought that Expression is for this purpose but I couldn't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, there's an attribute named *default* in activiti form properties that is used for this purpose.Older versions of Activiti Designer does not have this attribute in form properties editor, but in recent versions they added this attribute to editor.